# Double space integral formulation of homogeneous Sobolev norm

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, norms

Define for $u\in C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^n), 0<s<1$ the integral
$$
I_s(u) = \int_{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{n+n}} \frac{(u(x+y)-u(x))^2}{|y|^{d+2s}} dxdy.
$$
I wish to prove that for some $C=C(s)>1,$
$$
C^{-1}\|u\|_{\dot H^s} \leq I_s(u) \leq C\|u\|_{\dot H^s} .
$$
See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev%E2%80%93Slobodeckij_spaces) for a reference of this result.

I use the *definition* $\|u\|_{\dot H^s} = \||\xi|^s\hat u\|_{L^2}$, where $\hat{}$ denotes Fourier transform.

I try to apply Fouier transform over the integral on $x.$ I end up with an integral of the form
$$
\int \frac{(e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot y}-1)^2}{|y|^{d+2s}} |\hat u(\xi)|^2 dyd\xi,
$$
but apparently that does not provide a factor of $|\xi|^{2s}$ in the integrand. I can easily bound $I_s(u)$ by $\|u\|_{\dot H^1},$ but this is a weaker result than what we want.

**How to get the factor $|\xi|^{2s}$ into the integrand?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done half of the job. We have the absolutely convergent integral which is such that
$$
f(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{\vert e^{2iπ y\cdot \xi}-1\vert^2}{\vert y\vert^{d+2s}} dy
=c_{s,d}\vert \xi\vert^{2s},
$$
since for $A\in O(d)$, $f(A\xi)=f(\xi)$ (change of variables $y=Ay'$) and moreover for $\lambda >0$,
$f(\lambda \xi)=\lambda^{2s} f(\xi)$ (change of variables $y=y'/\lambda$).

Comment: What is the meaning of $O(d)$?

Comment: Does it mean the group of all orthogonal linear maps in $d$ dimensions?